# Jquery UI slider values calculated into a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

i need to make my jquery UI calculator to calculate from two different sliders, it should divide loan by age, and when age is over 40 it should add 10% discount, and when it's over 50 it should add 20% discount. Currently it displays the inital value, but when i move one slider the inital  value disappears, and when i change both sliders, it appears again, i need to make it so, when any slider is changed, it will change the value also, and would round it to 2 digits afters comma

```
 function slider_age() {

   var initialValue = 25;
    var sliderTooltip = function(event, ui) {
    var curValue = ui.value || initialValue;
    $('#slider-range-min .ui-slider-handle')
    var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-inner" style="margin-left:12px;">' + curValue + '</div><div class="tooltip-arrow" style="margin-left:2px;"  ></div></div>';


 $('#slider-range-min .ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip);

}




    $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: initialValue,
      step: 1,
      min: 18,
      max: 65,
      create: sliderTooltip,
      slide:  sliderTooltip,
       change: function(event, ui) {
      slider_age = ui.value; 
      changeValue(); 
     }




    });

};


function slider_sum() {
       var initialValue = 400000;

var sliderTooltip = function(event, ui) {


    var curValue2 = ui.value || initialValue;
    var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-inner">' + curValue2 + '</div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>';

   $('#slider-range-loan .ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip);
    return curValue2;
}
   $( "#slider-range-loan" ).slider({

    range: "min",   
    value: initialValue,
    min: 20000,
    max: 1000000,
    step: 1000,
    create: sliderTooltip,
    slide: sliderTooltip,

    change: function(event, ui) {
     slider_sum = ui.value;

     changeValue();
     }
    });
    var sum =  $( "#slider-range-loan" ).slider( "value" );
    var age=  $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) ;
    $( ".sum" ).html(sum/age);

  };
```

current Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/c8mnjn98/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize variables slider_sum, slider_age in function where they called, for example

```
function slider_age() {
    var initialValue = 25;
    ... 
    slider_age = initialValue;
    ... 
};


function slider_sum() {
    var initialValue = 400000;
    ... 
    slider_sum = initialValue;
    ....
};
```

DEMO-1: http://jsfiddle.net/c8mnjn98/2/

DEMO-2: http://jsfiddle.net/c8mnjn98/3/ - I have changed the names of variables from slider_age, slider_sum to  sliderAge, sliderSun in order to avoid confusion with the names of the function